# $http.get doesn't work with REST model using then() function

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

As you guys know, Angular recently deprecated the `http.get.success,error` functions. So this kind of calls are not recommended in your controller anymore:

```
$http.get("/myurl").success(function(data){
    myctrl.myobj = data;
}));
```

Rather, this kind of calls are to be used:

```
$http.get("/myurl").then(
    function(data) {
        myctrl.myobj = data;
    },
    function(error) {
        ...
    }
```

Problem is, simple Spring REST models aren't working with this new code. I recently downloaded a sample code with the above old success function and a REST model like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public Map<String,Object> home() {
    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello World");
    return model;
}
```

This should return a map like `{id:<someid>, content:"Hello World"}` for the `$http.get()` call, but it receives nothing - the view is blank.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you get it by using the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can: `{"id":"f77e3886-976b-4f38-b84d-ae4d322759d4","content":"Hello World"}`

Comment: Does it work with the `success()` instead then()?

Comment: And also try to `console.log(error)`

Comment: @Michelem Works with `success()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of the result is different. Its the response and not the data object directly.

[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) says :

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Properties of the response are

```
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
```

As the data object is required,

Please convert the code as

```
$http.get("/resource").then(
    function(response) {
        myctrl.myobj = response.data;
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

The first (of four) argument passed to `success()` is the data (i.e. body) of the response.

But the first (and unique) argument passed to `then()` is not the data. It's the full HTTP response, containing the data, the headers, the status, the config.

So what you actually need is

```
$http.get("/myurl").then(
    function(response) {
        myctrl.myobj = response.data;
    },
    function(error) {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: I'll try that and see.

Answer (score -1):

then must be return a new promise so you should handle it with defers.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('modelFromFactory', function($q) {
return {

        getModel: function(data) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var items = [];
          items.push({"id":"f77e3886-976b-4f38-b84d-ae4d322759d4","content":"Hello World"});
      deferred.resolve(items);
      return deferred.promise;
  }
};
});

function MyCtrl($scope,  modelFromFactory) {
modelFromFactory.getModel()
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.model = data;
})

}
```

Here is working fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/o16kg9p4/7/**

Comment: the answer is not relevant to the question. OP asks about handling http requests

Comment: i just want to show a new tradition he could do it with success but he asked us to work with another way. im trying to help him and u dislike so sad.

Comment: Just because you can write something doesn't mean it is required to be written. Deferreds are of no use in mentioned case

Comment: Thats why you are not a open source person. When you see a new solutions a case of use something you should share it with anothers. But people like you really annoying me.

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working for me. All it keeps showing is `{{model}}`.